# Git ignore files matching a pattern only

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory of images where I only want to `.gitignore` a specific subset of those images that match the pattern

```
\d{5}.png
```

Namely, `01001.png` or `93002.png`, for example.

For some reason, I'm not able to find the gitignore pattern for this or the bash glob that doesnt say 'too many arguments'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png
```

Comment: bash doesnt like that for an `ls` patter, so I figured it wouldnt in gitignore either, but it appears to work.

Comment: @cpjolicoeur bash does accept this pattern, at least `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release` does. Please refer http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: I know bash accepts it, that is why I tried to use it initially.  Try using it in bash on an `ls` command

Comment: I have tried with `ls` and it worked as expected, only files matching to the pattern were shown. http://pastebin.com/dw1cmYsR